# Permission based Authorization for different user roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a WebAPI microservice project in Dot Net Core 3.1. I am authenticating users in Azure AD. From Azure AD I am receiving **jwt token** for the User. This Jwt token along with other stuff also contains a role like this:

```
"roles": [
    "Engineer"
  ],
```

I have a **Database** which contains list of roles and permissions associated with them. Based on the permission associated with the role the user can have access to Put/Patch/Get API. Say, An Admin can access PUT as well as Patch API while a regular user( role - engineer) can only access Get API.

How do I authorize the user based on his role and permission that he holds. Any suggestion, ideas, Code sample or reference article would really help.

Thanks...

Edit: I don't want the exact answers, just a gist or guidance on how should I tackle this issue.. I am looking for solution on Internet for 2 3 days but couldn't find anything meaningful, that's why I asked here.

I will provide more details: I have referred a couple of links:
[Permission based Authorization](https://www.zehntec.com/blog/permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)

Here the author is grouping claims in roles. He is using Identity Framework to create roles and add claims. But I can't use that, as I am doing it with AD login jwt token. Also, to get my roles from the jwt token I need HTTPContext, which I cannot access in just any class, as of now it is only accessible in API Controller class, where I can get roles using the below code:

```
User.Identities.SelectMany(s => s.Claims).Where(s => s.Type.Contains("role")).Select(s => s.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

So, once I grab hold of the Roles, I will make a httpclient get call to my database service to get all the roles and permissions associated with that. But then how do I dynamically Authorize my API controllers Rest calls?

Comment: If you are not using Asp.net Core Identity, you could consider trying to use  cookie authentication. After getting the roles, you could use an authentication cookie to store the user information, check the following articles: [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Policy-Based And Role-Based Authorization In ASP.NET Core 3.0 Using Custom Handler](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/policy-based-role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured few ways to solve the conundrum. One way to do it was through [Custom Authorization Policy Providers using IAuthorizationPolicyProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

In the above method I would have created custom policy attributes like

```
[MinimumAccessAuthorize("Read","ModuleName1")]

[MinimumAccessAuthorize("Write","ModuleName2")]
```

on top of my Web API action methods and the IAuthorizationPolicyProvider would have taken care of the rest. The only problem to this approach was that I needed to hard code attributes for Read/Write access available for a module for every god dam action method in every controller here after.

Another approach to this problem was to come up with a custom middleware that authenticated user before the request could hit the controller.

So I created a custom middleware: [Resource for custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-extension-method)

Inside my middleware I had a function called invokeAsync

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, [FromServices] IRoleService roleService, [FromServices] IPermissionService permissionService)
    {
        var roles = context.User.Identities.SelectMany(s => s.Claims).Where(s => s.Type.Contains("role")).Select(s => s.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        if (roles == null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return;
        }

        var requestType = context.Request.Method;
        var controller = context.Request.Path.Value.Replace("/api/v1/", "").Split('/')[0];


        PermissionType typeRequired = requestType == "GET" ? PermissionType.Read : PermissionType.Write;

        var (IsSuccessRole, roleResult) = await roleService.GetRoleAsync();
        if (!IsSuccessRole)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return;
        }
        int _roleId = roleResult.Where(r => r.RoleName == roles).Select(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        var (IsSuccess, permissionResult) = await permissionService.GetPermissionAsync(_roleId);
        if (!IsSuccess)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return;
        }
        var validRoles = from p in permissionResult
                         join k in GetControllerModuleMaps()
                         on p.ProjectModule.ModuleName equals k.ModuleName
                         where k.ControllerName == controller && p.PermissionType >= typeRequired
                         select p.RoleId;

        if (!validRoles.Any())
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return;
        }
        await next(context);


    }
```

I am passing the HTTP context and 2 HTTP client services to get the permission and Roles data from the database.

I now check for the role of the user which is present in the jwt token through context and basic linq query.

then basic validation to see if the role is not null.

I check for the request type then to see if it is a GET, PUT or Patch request. Based on the request I store the value as enum in PermissionType.

I store the Controller details which will be hit by REST request in controller variable.

Now using the role service I query the database for the roleId associated with my current jwt token role. I then fetch the permissions associated with that roleID from Database using permission service.

Now based on the Successful query of permission from database, I write a Linq Query syntax where I do a join of the permission result data from database with a list of C# record containing the controller name and the module name as pair values(not key pair value).

Sample list of record looks like this:

```
    var toRet = new List<ControllerRecord>();

    toRet.Add(new ControllerRecord("Controller1", "Module 1"));
    toRet.Add(new ControllerRecord("Controller1", "Module 2"));
```

I check if my record of controllers match with the Request controller path and the permission associated with for that role in the database is greater than what is requested for in the Rest API ( this works because I have enums so NoAccess = 0 < GET request = Only Read = 1 < Put/Patch/Post request = Write = 2 )

If there is any valid role, I let the flow to continue as usual.

That's how I pulled this over...